# Fighter (Eldritch Knight)/Wizard multiclass spell known

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, multi-classing, eldritch-knight

I'm about to start a campaign and I wish to play an Eldritch Knight/Wizard multiclass. I've read the chapter 6 part for spellcasting:

> You determine 
>   what spells you know and can 
>   prepare for each class
>   individually, as if you were a
>   single-classed m em ber of 
>   that class. If you are a ranger
>   4/w izard 3, for example, 
>   you know three 1st-level ranger
>   spells based on your 
>   levels in the ranger class.

Now, since in that peculiar case the spells are from the same spellcasting class (the wizard), can I learn spells of higher level, for which I have spell slots, even if my single class level could not permit it?
For example: if I'm an EK-7/Wizard-3 (so with 4th level spell slots) can I learn 4th level spells?